# Vue3 - Recibir emit y añadir parametro a la función que lo recibe

Tags: typescript, vue3

Estoy recibiendo un emit de un componente, algo asi:

```
<chat @sendMessage="sendMessage"/>
```

la función recibe el mensaje de la siguiente manera

```
function sendMessage (message: string) {
 console.log(message)
}
```

la idea es agregar un parametro adicional dentro de la vista que utiliza el componente:

```
<chat @sendMessage="sendMessage(emit, otroParametro)"/>
```

y luego recibirlo

```
function sendMessage (message: string, param: string) {
 console.log(message)
 console.log(param)
}
```

espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
<chat
 @sendMessage="sendMessage($event, 'parámetro adicional')"
/>
```

y la función como cualquier otra:

```
 function sendMessage (message: string, param: string) {
   console.log(message) // mensaje emitido por el componente
   console.log(param) // 'parámetro adicional'
}
```